# free() the reserved data with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, c99

Hi 
 I have written this Program which create a list of books which is given by the User and i can't free the my_value at the end of program and get a lot of errors . 
 This is my Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){



int n;
printf("Please Enter the Number of Books:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
char **array=(char *) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char *));

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
char *my_value=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
printf("Please Enter the Name of the %dth Book:\n",i+1);
scanf("%s",my_value);
*(array+i)=my_value;
free(my_value);

}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 printf("\n The Book Nr.%d is %s \n",i+1,*(array+i));
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 free(array[i]);
}
free(array);


return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What sort of errors do you get?  Which platform are you developing on?  Have you used [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?  You should show some sample data and report the errors you get from that sample data.  Maybe just two books worth of data; that'd be sufficient, probably.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), noting that data and output (actual vs expected) are both parts of an MCVE.

Comment: You do not need to cast the result of `malloc`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Additionally, `char **array=(char *) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char *))` has incompatible pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in

```
char **array=(char *) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char *));
```

you don't need `n+1` pointers since you use only `n`.

Then, this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
}
```

is unnecessary (and wrong). `array[i]` is to be overwritten just after.

In the next loop

```
*(array+i)=my_value; // is array[i] = my_value
free(my_value);      // <=== why? remove that line!
```

you free what you just allocated -- `array[i]` cannot be used anymore from that point! Lead to undefined behavior.